# How do I change the Google Maps draggable property for the map (not the marker)?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, draggable

In the [Google Maps v3 reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference), I see there is a method `setDraggable(boolean)` which can be applied to a map marker.

However, I want to set `setDraggable` to `true` on the **map**, *not* on a map marker.

I have set the property `draggable` to `false` in the mapOptions, but I don't know how to set this to `true` later...  `map.setDraggable(true)` does *not* work:

```
    // object literal for map options
    var myOptions =
    {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.09024, -95.712891),
        zoom: 4, // smaller number --> zoom out
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN,

        // removing all map controls
        disableDefaultUI: true,

        // prevents map from being dragged
        draggable: false,

        // disabling all keyboard shortcuts
        keyboardShortcuts: false,

        disableDoubleClickZoom: true,

        // do not clear the map div     
        noClear: true
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

    map.setDraggable(true); // does NOT work!
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try:

```
map.setOptions({draggable: true});
```

Comment: Thanks @Marcelo, that did the trick! I was not aware of `setOptions`, and how easy it is to access the map options this way.

Comment: @Marcelo, thak you very much!

Comment: This is deprecated. See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/releases#331

Answer (score 1):

I entered my code in this section and it worked on mobile and desktop

```
function initialize()
    {
    var mapProp = {
      center:myCenter,
      zoom:5,
      draggable:false,
      mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      };
```

Answer (score 0):

setDraggable is not used in the Map class.

It is used in the:

**Marker Class**,
**Polyline class**,
**Polygon class**,
**Rectangle class** and in the **Circle class**.

In your case you can simply use:

```
map.draggable = true;
```